# Django can't find HTML file

Tags: django, templates, django-urls

I have a html file ('search.html') with a form on it. I have saved it to ~/Django/Templates just for the sake of argument. The Django book said it doesn't matter where I save it, because the framework will find it. Anyway, I have set up a function in the views.py file to render this file. Here it is:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def search(request):
 return render_to_response('search.html')
```

I have this function called in the urls.py file as well:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
 (r'^$', index),
 (r'^search/$', search),
```

However, whenever I go to visit the page with the ~/search in the URL, I get the following:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /search/

What's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your settings.py file there is a line...

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (...)
```

You want to make sure the directory containing the template is in that tuple.